¿Por que en un crud de laravel de de uno a muchos, me crea, pero no me actualiza ni elimina?
Estoy haciendo un crud de Subcategorias, me tiene que mostrar el nombre de subcategoria y la categoria a la que pertenece(la categoria ya esta creada en otro crud)(1Caregoria NSubcategorias). El crud es hecho con ventanas modales de bootstrap. Todo bien para crear la subcategoria y que me la muestre, lo malo es que al editar y eliminar el registro queda igual, entro al modal edito y cuando le doy guardar no me edita nada, lo mismo con delete. Cabe recalcar que en el index.blade ya esta el include de create, el de update y delete
modelo categoria
   protected $table = 'categorias';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombreCategoria'

    ];

    protected $guarded = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected function nombreCategoria(): Attribute{

        return Attribute::make(
            // mutador
           set: fn($value) => strtolower($value),
            // accesor
           get: fn($value) => ucfirst($value)
        );
    }

    public function subcategorias(): HasMany{
            return $this->hasMany(Subcategoria::class, 'categoria_id', 'id');

    }

modelo subcategoria
use HasFactory;

protected $table = 'subcategorias';

// protected $primaryKey = 'id';


protected $fillable = ['nombreSubcategoria','categoria_id'];

protected $guarded = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

public function categoria(): BelongsTo{

    return $this->belongsTo(Categoria::class, 'categoria_id', 'id');
}

StoreCategoriaRequest:
return [

        'nombreSubcategoria' => 'required|string|max:30|unique:subcategorias,nombreSubcategoria',
        'categoria_id' => 'required|exists:categorias,id',
   
];

controlador:
public function index(){

   
    $subcategorias = Subcategoria::with('categoria')
    ->select('subcategorias.id','subcategorias.nombreSubcategoria', 'categorias.nombreCategoria')
    ->join('categorias', 'subcategorias.categoria_id', '=', 'categorias.id')
    ->paginate(6);

    
    $categorias = DB::table('categorias')->select('id','nombreCategoria')->get();
    return view('subcategorias.index', compact('subcategorias', 'categorias'));

    
}

public function create(){
    return view('subcategorias.create');
}


public function store(StoreSubcategoriaRequest $request){
    
    Subcategoria::create([

        'nombreSubcategoria' => $request->input('nombreSubcategoria'),
        'categoria_id' => $request->input('categoria_id')

    ]);
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function update(Request $request, Subcategoria $subcategorias) {

    $request->validate([
        'nombreSubcategoria' => "required|string|max:30|unique:subcategorias,nombreSubcategoria,{$subcategorias->id}",
        'categoria_id' => 'required|exists:categorias,id',
    ]);

    $subcategorias->update([
            'nombreSubcategoria' => $request->input('nombreSubcategoria'),
        'categoria_id' => $request->input('categoria_id')

    ]);

    return redirect()->back();
}


public function destroy(Subcategoria $subcategorias){

        $subcategorias->delete();
        return redirect()->back();
}

index.blade
   <thead class="bg-dark text-white">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Subcategoria</th>
            <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
            <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach ($subcategorias as $s)
           <tr>
            <td>{{$s->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$s->nombreSubcategoria}}</td>
            <td>{{$s->nombreCategoria}}</td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal"   data-bs-target="#edit{{$s->id}}">
                Editar
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-bs-toggle="modal"    data-bs-target="#delete{{$s->id}}">Eliminar</button>
            </td>
           </tr>
           <div>
            @include('subcategorias.update')
          </div>
           
           <div>
            @include('subcategorias.delete')
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>

        

AQUI MI update.blade
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{$s->id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar subcategoria</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
        <form action="{{ route('subcategorias.update', $s->id) }}" method="post">
          @csrf
          @method('PUT')
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="nombreSubcategoria">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombreSubcategoria" class="form-control" value="{{ 
               old('nombreSubcategoria', $s->nombreSubcategoria) }}" required>
            
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="categoria_id" class="form-label">Categoría</label>
              <select name="categoria_id" id="categoria_id" class="form-control" required>
                <option disabled {{ old('categoria_id') ? '' : 'selected' }}>Select one</option>
                @foreach ($categorias as $categoria)
                <option value="{{ $categoria->id }}" {{ $s->categoria_id == $categoria->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $categoria->nombreCategoria }}</option>
                @endforeach
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </form>

delete.blade
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete{{$s->id}}" tabindex="-1"   aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Contenido del modal -->
        <form action="{{route('subcategorias.destroy', $s->id)}}" method="post">
          @csrf
          @method('DELETE')
          <div class="modal-body">
             ¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar la subcategoria "<strong>{{$s->nombreSubcategoria}}</strong>" ?
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Proceder</button>
          </div>
        </form>


Podrias incluir el codigo de los modelos Categoria y Subcateogoria?

Modelos agregados

Listo, ya actualiza y elimina perfecto, lo que hice en los métodos del controlador update y delete, en ves de $subcategorias $subcategoria, en minúscula, no se el  por qué ?, todavía estoy intentando entender porque antes no y ahora si con ese cambio de plural a singular, debe ser algo del controlador o vistas jejeje

Cuando usas moddl binding, el nombre del parametro en la ruta y el nombre de la variable que inyectas en la función debe ser el mismo https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-model-binding
